# Server tag not well formed. Why?

Tags: asp.net

I keep getting the parser error message:

> The server tag is not well formed.

But to me it looks fine:

```
<asp:Button ID="seat" CommandArgument="<%#(Eval("SeatName"))%>"    
     CommandName="takeSeat" Text="<%#(Eval("SeatName"))%>" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using <% whatever %> you have to use the single ('  not ") '<% whatever %>' and NOT "<% whatever %>".

So

```
<asp:Button ID="seat" CommandArgument='<%#(Eval("SeatName"))%>'     CommandName="takeSeat" Text='<%#(Eval("SeatName"))%>' runat="server" />
```